# iOS 6 is slow to paint view when using modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

Tags: iphone, performance, ios6, iphone-4

I recently upgraded my iPhone 4 to iOS 6. Upon doing so I noticed that one of the apps I'm working on is no longer behaving as expected when presenting a modal dialog.

I am using UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal.

The problem is that during the animation I see what I can only describe as intermediate paint states of the view. I momentarily see the view partially painted, then finally the entire view is drawn. I have never experienced this before iOS 6.

The flow is as follows:

ViewController decides it's time to present a modal dialog to the user:

```
    self.newController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PaginatedView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.newController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentModalViewController:self.newController animated:YES];
```

NewViewController initializes views for pages:

(called from NewViewController:initWithNibName:bundle:)

```
NSUInteger pages = 2;
CGFloat cx = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < pages ; i++) {
    // Load the view from nib
    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SomeView" owner:nil options:nil];
    SomeView*  someView = (SomeView*)[nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    [someView initializeWithData:[_objects objectAtIndex:i]];
    [someView setParentController:self];
    [someView setBackButtonTarget:self withSelector:@selector(backButtonClick:)];

    // Set the x origin for the view
    CGRect viewRect = someView.frame;
    viewRect.origin.x = ((self.scrollView.frame.size.width - viewRect.size.width) / 2) + cx;
    viewRect.origin.y = ((self.scrollView.frame.size.height - viewRect.size.height) / 2);
    someView.frame = viewRect;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:someView];
    cx += self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
}

self.pageControl.numberOfPages = pages;
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
```

The object SomeView is a view that displays a table to the user. When the animation is playing I momentarily see the table and its header empty, then finally the content comes in.

Switching modalTransitionStyle to any other style resolves the issue, but I'd like to use UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal.

Any ideas as to what is happening and how I can fix it?

Also, I tried this on an iPhone 4S running iOS 6. No problems... Looks like iOS 6 made the iPhone 4 experience crappy...